# how do i make a profile page with posts

Tags: php, mysql, posts, profiles

Basically if the title is to cryptic (i don't know how to make it sound right)

I want it to say there is a profile.php?id=1234 or something similar and basically have a database with posts that have an id that id corresponds to id=1234 so the posts have one database but go to a specific profile much like a chan and their boards.

I have pretty good knowledge of php and beginner at mysql im wondering how this can be done and i hope i this makes sense

Comment: I am sorry, but this doesn't make much sense too me. Can you show an example (eg: a link)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you need:

```
SELECT * FROM posts
WHERE user_id = yourid
```

where `yourid` could be `$_GET["id"]`.
Naturally you **MUST** sanitize user input to avoid SQL Injection: never use user inupt directly in a query!!